# Is multiple class assignment in the example html that gulp-svg-sprite provides possible?

Tags: svg, gulp, sprite

Using the gulp-svg-sprite plugin, I'm able to get an example html which uses the generated svg sprite. There, the <svg>s which <use> the <symbol>s automatically have a class according to the shape ID.

This class is of the form `mode.<mode>.prefix` (prefix, default value `".svg-%s"`) + `mode.<mode>.dimensions` (suffix, default value `"-dims"`).

Is there any way I can get multiple classes for the <svg> in the generated html? It will be so much easier to copy and paste the markup from this file. Eg. `<svg class="class1 class2">`. gulp-svg-sprite always only produces one class.

I've tried

- Just leaving a space between my desired class names in both `mode.<mode>.prefix` and `mode.<mode>.suffix`. Eg. `prefix: "icon-svg %s"`.
- Escaping the space (with \), but maybe that doesn't make sense here.
- Give different classes simultaneously in both `mode.<mode>.prefix` and `mode.<mode>.suffix`. Eg. `prefix: "icon-svg"`, `dimensions: " icon-%s"`.

My config object:

```
var svgSpriteConfig = {
  dest: imagesPath,
  shape: {
    id: {
      separator: '',          // no directory namespacing
      generator: 'icon-%s'    // symbol ID prefix
    }
  },
  mode: {
    symbol: {
      dest: '.',
      inline: true,
      prefix: '',             // class prefix
      dimensions: '%s',       // class suffix
      sprite: './icons-sprite.svg',
      example: true
    }
  }
};
```

An important point to note: `prefix` can be empty, but `dimensions` cannot.